# How can I copy data/installation files between drives? Windows 11

Tags: windows, ssd, file-transfer

I have 4 different SSD's in my workstation and after doing some file management/moving things around I have decided to designate 1 drive for installations and use the others for Windows Installation and file/media storage. Is there a program out there to transfer the data/programs between the drives saving me the time of reinstalling? If I do have to reinstall, is there a way to back up data for the programs so that at least that is not lost? Several of the items I have installed are games that I would not like to restart  I'm running Windows 11. Ideally, I could move the install files for the different programs/games without having to reinstall them. If reinstall is necessary, is there a way to backup/transfer the data for these programs?

Comment: @Jim - Super User isn’t a forum

Comment: I'd edit your question to make it more clear but you are asking at least 3 different questions here and I do not know which one you want to focus on. Please edit your question to remove the software requests and to focus on a single specific question so we can get you a single specific answer. Multiple posts is fine here, multiple questions in a single post is not fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Though this is not the *site* [not forum] for software recommendations, [StackExchange Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is. You should break this question down into separate pieces, and ask part here.
2. OTTOMH, leave the Windows OS where it is, and all program files, as well, since most applications *require* installation *on the Windows partition*.
3. Moving Windows Special Folders, Documents, Downloads, Music,  Pictures and Videos to other SSD's can [be done easily](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/move-or-restore-default-location-of-music-folder-in-windows-11.8712/).

- **Using Windows *Explorer***

  - Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open *Explorer*.
  - Navigate to the location of the new System folder, e.g., where *Documents* should go on second, third or fourth SSD, and create a *new* folder, *Documents*, there.
  - Navigate to the **current** *Documents* folder, e.g., `C:\Users\Jim\Documents*.
  - Right-click that folder, select *Properties*.
  - Note the number of files and folders for future reference.
  - Open *Location* tab.

    [image: Moving Documents]
  - Click *Move* button and select the **new** *Documents* folder and click *OK*.
  - Confirm that you want to move all in the old *Documents* location to the new.
  - Wait for this to complete... If there are many files, this can take some time even with fast SSD's.
  - **Verify** that all all files and folders, from the original count, are in the new location. If not, move them manually.
- There are other tools, such as Nirsoft's free [Special Folders View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html) that can show the folder locations.